# Not able inject bean in the component

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have implemented Spring Quartz scheduler example using [this link](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-quartz-2-scheduler-integration-annotation-example-using-javaconfig)  
I am having simple MyJobTwo.java component that has a method `executeInternal()` that is being called using `CronTriggerFactoryBean`.

This is my **QuartzConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("com.example") 
public class QuartzConfiguration {
    // we need to create a bean that will excuted by MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean
    // in this case we have myJobOne is the simple bean

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean methodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean() {
        MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean obj = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        obj.setTargetBeanName("myJobOne");
        obj.setTargetMethod("myTask");
        return obj;
    }

    // This trigger will schedule the job after 3 seconds and repeat after every 30 seconds for 3+1 times.
    @Bean
    public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean simpleTriggerFactoryBean(){
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
       stFactory.setJobDetail(methodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        stFactory.setRepeatInterval(30000);
        stFactory.setRepeatCount(1);
        return stFactory;
    }

    // We use it to configure complex job such as job scheduling using cron-expression
    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean(){
        JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobClass(MyJobTwo.class);
        // Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        // map.put("myJobOne", myJobOne);
        // map.put(MyJobTwo.myJodOne, 1);
        //factory.setJobDataAsMap(map);
        //factory.setGroup("mygroup");
        //factory.setName("myjob");
        return factory;
    }

    // CronTriggerFactoryBean configures JobDetailFactoryBean
    // We also configure start delay, trigger name, and cron-expression to schedule the job

    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(){
        CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        stFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        //stFactory.setName("mytrigger");
        //stFactory.setGroup("mygroup");
        stFactory.setCronExpression("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *");
        return stFactory;
    }

    // SchedulerFactoryBean use to register the triggers 
    // those registered triggers will be executed
    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
        //scheduler.setTriggers(simpleTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

This is the bean that I am executing using CronTriggerFactoryBean.

**MyJobTwo.java**

```
@Component
public class MyJobTwo extends QuartzJobBean {

    private SmtpMailSender smtpMailSender;

    @Autowired
    public MyJobTwo(MyJobOne myJobOne, SmtpMailSender smtpMailSender) {
        super();
        this.myJobOne = myJobOne;
        this.smtpMailSender = smtpMailSender;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("this is the test");
        myJobOne.myTask();
        System.out.println("task is done");
    }

}
```

Whenever I am trying to inject other beans and service I am getting these errors. Anyone having any idea what is causing these errors, what changes do I need to make?

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.job.MyJobTwo
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.createJobInstance(AdaptableJobFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.job.MyJobTwo.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think you need a default construktor in your class MyJobTwo. Because of the error "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.job.MyJobTwo.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)"

Comment: could you please give an example ?

Comment: sure:

@Component
public class MyJobTwo extends QuartzJobBean {

@ Autowired
private SmtpMailSender smtpMailSender;

@ Autowired
MyJobOne myJobOne;


public MyJobTwo () {
super(); 
}

.....your code ...

Comment: I have tried this but getting null pointer exception.

Comment: hm because of the smtpMailSender or the myJobOne?

Comment: `package com.example.job;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component("myJobOne")
public class MyJobOne {

 public void myTask() {
 
     System.out.println("This is my task");
    }
 
}
` this is myJobOne.java class it is simple I am just using it for testing dependency injection. now I have removed smtpmailsender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default job factory implementation `AdaptableJobFactory` doesn't have autowiring capability.
To use dependency injection do following:

1.Create job factory

```
package com.concretepage.config;

import org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory;

public class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);  //the magic is done here
        return job;
    }
}
```

Implementation is found on http://codrspace.com/Khovansa/spring-quartz-with-a-database/

2.Update schedulerFactoryBean declaration in QuartzConfiguration:

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    scheduler.setTriggers(simpleTriggerFactoryBean().getObject(), cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
    scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory());
    return scheduler;
}

@Bean
public JobFactory jobFactory() {
    return new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
}
```

3. Use setter-based injection instead of constructor injection

Comment: Thanks Evgeny Baranov.- can you please explain bit about it ?

Comment: if you take a look at AdaptableJobFactory source code you'll see that createJobInstance method uses default constructor to instantiate job and that is all. So it doesn't provide any DI functionality. AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory performs injection by invocation of  beanFactory.autowireBean(job)