# Initilizing a constructor and inject a Repository bean of Jpa in Quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I want to do some job in my event(CrudRepository(IgniteRepository)) repository. But when I have a constructor even the empty constructor I get an exception.

```
public class UpdateStatusJob implements Job {

    private TaskRepository TaskRepo;

    // UpdateStatusJob(){}


     UpdateStatusJob(TaskRepository taskRepo) throws
     JobExecutionException
     { 

       this.taskRepo= taskRepo; 

     }


    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("Events!!!!!");
    }


   }
```

**Exception :**

> org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
>           at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45)
>           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
>           at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:392)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   com.mphasis.eventinsights.scheduler.UpdateStatusJob
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
>           at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.createJobInstance(AdaptableJobFactor
>   y.java:58)
>   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.jp.tande.scheduler.UpdateStatusJob.()
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)

I need taskRepo to do some operations but failing call constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able inject bean in the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651601/not-able-inject-bean-in-the-component) (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858687/spring-cannot-inject-bean-in-class-that-implements-quartz-job))

Comment: @Morfic Getting null pointer exception if I am implementing according to above link

Comment: And what did your investigation of the NPE reveal?

Comment: @Morfic Thanks I solved it....was checking something silly....thanks your linked helped me to solve the problem